# .htaccess rewrite rule for two GET variables HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: .htaccess, http, variables, https, get

I have successfully been able to redirect my two variables using the following code, but if the search engine indexes it as https, then I have not been able to find a way to redirect it to the non secure version.

Code for redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\.html$ group/user.php?uid=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ group/user.php?uid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\/\.])+[\/]([^\/\.]+)[\.]html$ group/user.php?uid=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Correctly makes: testdomain.com/test/page.html

but somehow the page got indexed in google as a secure page, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to create a redirect from the https version to http.

My goal is to take https://www.testdomain.com/test/page.html and redirect to http://www.testdomain.com/test/page.html

Any help would be very helpful.